# Не получается отправить данные с jsp на сервлет

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

Хочу написать вэб приложение, чтобы параметр принимался через файл `index.jsp`, передавался сервлету, обрабатывался и выводился в обозревателе. Простая программа, но у меня не получается и я не могу понять почему.

Код jsp файла:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="/numbOutput/src/main/resources/ReturnNumberServlet">
Enter the number: <input type="text" name="number">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Код сервлета:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class ReturnNumberServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse      response) throws ServletException, IOException { 
    String number = request.getParameter("number");
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
    pw.println("the selected number is: "+number);
    pw.close();
  }
}
```

Структура файлов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

запускается и отрабатывает jsp-файл:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
результат выполнения программы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться, если кто знает, как это делать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, не кладите java-файлы в `src/main/resources`, кладите их в `src/main/java`.

Во вторых, ваша форма шлет запрос к `"/numbOutput/src/main/resources/ReturnNumberServlet"`. Т.е. вы явно указали путь к файлу на диске, да еще и к исходнику. На самом деле там должен быть тот путь, который назначен сервлету `ReturnNumberServlet` в файле `web.xml` (который вы не привели).

Например. В `web.xml` задан такой маппинг:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>returnNumber</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ReturnNumberServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>returnNumber</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/returnNumber</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

где:

- `returnNumber` - логическое имя сервлета;
- `ReturnNumberServlet` - имя класса сервлета;
- `/servlet/returnNumber` - URL, назначенный сервлету.

Тогда форму можно будет направить на описанный URL:

```
<form action="servlet/returnNumber">
```

Comment: Спасибо, заработало. Действительно дело было в расположении java-файла

Answer (score 2):

Вы батенька знаете что такое файл web.xml? В нем ведь описывается способ трансляции пути в сервлет. [Почитайте документацию](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/webapp/configureservlet.html)